# How to add more than two devices with PowerCLI

Tags: powercli, esxi, vcenter

I am trying to setup hardware passthrough on a ESXi 6.0 server with the following PowerCLI script:

```
    Connect-VIServer $server -User $user -Password $pwd

    $AllVirtualMachines = Get-VM -Location "Dev Machines"

    foreach ($VirtualMachine in $AllVirtualMachines)
    {   
    Get-PassthroughDevice -VM $VirtualMachine | Remove-PassthroughDevice -Confirm:$false
    }
    foreach ($VirtualMachine in $AllVirtualMachines)
    {   
    $PciDeviceList = Get-PassthroughDevice -VMHost 172.16.7.130 -Type Pci
    Add-PassthroughDevice -VM $VirtualMachine -PassthroughDevice $PciDeviceList[0] -Confirm:$false
    }
    foreach ($VirtualMachine in $AllVirtualMachines)
    {   
    $PciDeviceList = Get-PassthroughDevice -VMHost 172.16.7.130 -Type Pci
    Add-PassthroughDevice -VM $VirtualMachine -PassthroughDevice $PciDeviceList[1] -Confirm:$false
    }
    foreach ($VirtualMachine in $AllVirtualMachines)
    {   
    $PciDeviceList = Get-PassthroughDevice -VMHost 172.16.7.130 -Type Pci
    Add-PassthroughDevice -VM $VirtualMachine -PassthroughDevice $PciDeviceList[2] -Confirm:$false
    }
    foreach ($VirtualMachine in $AllVirtualMachines)
    {   
    $PciDeviceList = Get-PassthroughDevice -VMHost 172.16.7.130 -Type Pci
     Add-PassthroughDevice -VM $VirtualMachine -PassthroughDevice $PciDeviceList[3] -Confirm:$false
    }
```

...and it works great...for two devices. After any two PCI devices are setup with a hardware passthrough I will be given a message of "The maximum number of PCI devices has been reached". However I can go in via the GUI and add all the PCI devices I want...I've had as many as nine devices on one VM.

The devices I am trying to add are NVMe drives if it matters.

Comment: Any updates on this? Same issue. I see multiple reports online. No solutions

Comment: Sorry, I never did get any answer for this...not even from VMware. As in no response to this issue at all. Even with a service contract.